# How to fix 'Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string' when using collection diff function

Tags: laravel, collections

I'm having this problem when I try to use the function  of collections diff on two collections that I've created from laravel DB, they have the same structure :

```
$diff = $reservations->diff($pitches);
```

the two collection from a dump :

```
/home/vagrant/projets/fffff/app/Http/Controllers/API/SizeController.php:126:
object(Illuminate\Support\Collection)[266]
  protected 'items' => 
    array (size=6)
      0 => 
        object(stdClass)[271]
          public 'id' => int 1
      1 => 
        object(stdClass)[265]
          public 'id' => int 2
      2 => 
        object(stdClass)[270]
          public 'id' => int 3
      3 => 
        object(stdClass)[272]
          public 'id' => int 4
      4 => 
        object(stdClass)[276]
          public 'id' => int 5
      5 => 
        object(stdClass)[275]
          public 'id' => int 6
```

And

```
/home/vagrant/projets/fffff/app/Http/Controllers/API/SizeController.php:127:
object(Illuminate\Support\Collection)[274]
  protected 'items' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => 
        object(stdClass)[282]
          public 'id' => int 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be careful when comparing an [`Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Collection`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Collection.php#L293) with an [`Illuminate/Support/Collection`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Support/Collection.php#L205), the `diff()` function works differently in each of them.

In the given case I would `pluck` the unique property from the second collection and use `whereNotIn`.

```php
$diff = $reservations->whereNotIn('id', $pitches->pluck('id'));
```